# Solving VRP based on least demand or less distance. Optimizing routes for other variables

Tags: routes, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm trying to model a node coverage problem, and in my case I'm using capacity per vehicle `routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity` but I want to change the solution based on optimal route or route that uses least of the capacity. The use case is salt in a snow plowing situation.

As far as I can tell there are `first_solution_strategy` and `local_search_metaheuristic` but nothing else to define what kind of solution to find. Is this possible with OR-Tools?